# JOGL: getGL() from GLJPanel?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm attempting to convert an application from `GLCanvas` to `GLJPanel`.

What's the best way to get the GL object (`getGL()`) from a `GLJPanel`?

Alternatively, I could create my own context from `getNativeSurface()`, but this function returns `null` with `GLJPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely get the `GL` instance by calling [GLAutoDrawable.getGL()](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GLAutoDrawable.html#getGL()) or [GLContext.getCurrentGL()](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GLContext.html#getCurrentGL()) in [GLEventListener.display(GLAutoDrawable)](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GLEventListener.html#display(com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable)). If one of these methods returns `null` or throws a `GLException`, it means that the OpenGL context isn't current on this thread.

Please don't store the `GL` instance into a field, use it only locally, follow the recommendations of our user's guide, this instance can become invalid at any time, a new `GL` instance might be used at the next frame.

By the way, rather ask the questions specific to JOGL on [our official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org/jogl-f782158.html).